# Unable to bind to nonstandard ports in Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

I am working on doing my usual changes to a fairly fresh install, and one of them is to change my sshd port from 22 to port 9 to reduce the amount of logspam caused by botnets. I do this by editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but when restarting sshd via `systemctl restart sshd`, I get this in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Oct  2 19:01:01 mindflayer sshd[6518]: error: Bind to port 9 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Permission denied.
Oct  2 19:01:01 mindflayer sshd[6518]: error: Bind to port 9 on :: failed: Permission denied.
Oct  2 19:01:01 mindflayer sshd[6518]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
```

I'm mostly a debian guy, so it would not surprise me if this is related to a security measure implemented by Centos 7.

I also experienced the same when trying to set up a temporary web server on port 81, but as it was not important at that moment, I did not investigate further, but I believe it is the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust selinux rules:

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp new_port_number
```

Comment: Almost, but close enough to accept, as it got me on the right track: `semanage port -m -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 9` - Modify, not add. Otherwise it complains about port 9 already being defined, as it's reserved for bitbucket.